# Java String Split/Remove for n number of special charactor parts

Tags: java, string

Input

```
String s1 = "This Payer Ref [customerRef] does not exist/This Card Ref [cardRef] has already been used."
```

I want to remove all the parts with [variable]

Output

```
"This Payer Ref does not exist/This Card Ref has already been used."
```

Please note there can be n number of `[variable]` in the given string.

I tried many ways but no luck.

Comment: What *many ways* did you try?

Comment: @ernest_k string replace and split methods..

Comment: Please add that attempt to your post. It shows that you've tried solving it yourself, and prevents the question from being closed as too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`String::replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) which use regex, with this one [`\[.*?\]`](https://regex101.com/r/dAq6Lb/1) like so :

```
s1 = s1.replaceAll("\\[.*?\\]", "").replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ");
```

Output

```
This Payer Ref does not exist/This Card Ref has already been used.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this.

```
String s1 = "This Payer Ref [customerRef] does not exist/This Card Ref [cardRef] has already been used.";
s1=s1.replaceAll("\\[\\w+\\]", "");
System.out.println(s1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `replaceAll` with lazy matching:

```
String s1 = "This Payer Ref [customerRef] does not exist/This Card Ref [cardRef] has already been used.";
String s2 = s1.replaceAll("\\[.*?] ?", "");
System.out.println(s2);
```

Result is:

```
This Payer Ref does not exist/This Card Ref has already been used.
```

Notice that you have to remove one trailing space after each `[variable]`

Read more about lazy matching here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_matching

Comment: Your solution will not work is the brackets are in the end for example `"..[cardRef] has already [been used.]"` :)

Comment: You're right. needs to add `?` at the end od the regex. edited :)

Comment: I would use `*` to match zero or more instead of `?` :) nice fix +1